# Proving that an Isolated Singularity is removable.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading the book Complex Analysis by Lars V Ahlfors. I was unable to solve the exercise below:

Prove that an isolated singularity of $f(z)$ is removable as soon as either $Re f(z)$ or $Im f(z)$ is bounded from above or below.Hint: Apply fractional linear transformation

My Try:

I could prove that if the function is bounded then it has a removable singularity. But I am unable to understand how to prove that if just real part is bounded . I could not even figure out how to use a fractional linear transformation to prove this. If any one can give some hints as to how to use the fractional linear transformation to prove it , it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hint: Apply fractional linear transformation

Means take a fractional linear transformation $T$ that maps the half-plane $\{ z : \operatorname{Re} z > c\}$ (or $< c$, or the imaginary part) to a bounded domain (a disk), and look at the function

$$g(z) = T(f(z)),$$

which is then bounded on a punctured neighbourhood of the singularity. Deduce from the removability of $g$'s isolated singularity that of $f$'s.

Comment: thanks a lot but I am still having problem in deducing that $f$ has removable singularity. Because I took the inverse of the linear transformation say it is $\frac{z+1}{z-1}$. Then if the value of $g$ at the removable singularity becomes equal to 1. Then I do not know how to proceed further

Comment: That cannot happen. Let's suppose you know that $\operatorname{Re} f(z) > 0$. You can always achieve that by a rotation and translation, so it doesn't lose generality. Then you consider for example $$g(z) = \frac{f(z)-1}{f(z)+1}.$$ So you know $\lvert g(z)\rvert < 1$ in a punctured neighbourhood of $z_0$. You problem is "what would happen if $g(z_0) = 1$?" Well, the maximum principle says that then $g$ would be constant (in a neighbourhood of $z_0$), but that contradicts the strict inequality $\lvert g(z)\rvert < 1$ in the punctured neighbourhood.

Comment: Why would $|g(z)| < 1$?